# The page isn’t redirecting properly error while accessing http://localhost:8080/login in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

I am developing authentication and authorization using spring security. I want to test the access control in this application. When I tried to access the */product/welcome* route, the app return 403 Forbidden. Then I added a permitAll permission for the login page.

When I try to access http://localhost:8080, the browser says

*The page isn’t redirecting properly*
*Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.*

My SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.cde.backend.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    //authentication
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("Alice")
                .password(encoder.encode("Pwd1"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("John")
                .password(encoder.encode("Pwd2"))
                .roles("USER","ADMIN","HR")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable()).formLogin(form->form.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/product/welcome").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/product/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).build();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }



}
```

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cde</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>Web Portal</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mindrot/jbcrypt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here in your case:

```
auth
                        .requestMatchers("/product/welcome").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/product/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

You are telling that every request to `/product/welcome` permit to all but after it you have `/product/**` to be admin role, it mean that every path and sub paths to `/product` should be with admin roles. To fix it just move path of your `/welcome` to new one path and that all.

Something like this

```
auth
                        .requestMatchers("/welcome/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/product/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

And also you will have another controller class with this path and method that return welcome page.

Comment: I added the fix but it didn't worked because I am not able to access the login form, if I keep this, `.formLogin(form->form.loginPage("/login").permitAll())`, I am still getting the same error and after removing it, the page renders blank

Comment: do you have a custom login form ?

Comment: Can you also update the question with current implementation ?